# How to construct unit tests combining Robolectric and AndroidX with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, robolectric, androidx-test

### Assumptions

- Robolectric controls which Android version to emulate, so I need this
- AndroidX has the test API for Jetpack Compose, so I need this as well

### Background

I have experienced a lot of [AppNotIdleException](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/AppNotIdleException) when running the full test suite, but most often they run successfully in isolation (related: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/7055). I would like to understand exactly how these two APIs should be combined to avoid problems.

For starters there is a configuration called ["Looper mode"](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/latest/org/robolectric/annotation/LooperMode.Mode.html) in Robolectric, which basically defines when different threads are executed. [The default value, since Robolectric 4.5, is "PAUSED"](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/4.5/org/robolectric/annotation/LooperMode.Mode.html) which means the developer should control when threads are executed.

In addition AndroidX offers [createComposeRule()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/test/junit4/package-summary#createComposeRule()) which makes it possible to build minimal unit tests with a single composable - very nice.
[This "Compose rule" comes with a "mainClock" with the default behavior to "auto-advance"](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/test/MainTestClock).

### Question

Given a simple composable with a button. **What is the recommended setup (annotations, clock configs, etc) for my test?** Let's assume I want the test to run for Android P (API=28). Any feedback is welcome. I want to keep the tests as tidy as possible.

### Code

This is how I would write my tests today:

```kotlin
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.P])
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED)
class MyComposablesKtTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    private val buttonNode get() = composeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescription("My Button")

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        composeTestRule.mainClock.autoAdvance = false
    }

    @Test
    fun `MyComposable - always - sets up view correctly`() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            MyComposable(onClick = {})
        }
        composeTestRule.mainClock.advanceTimeByFrame()

        buttonNode.assertExists().assertHasClickAction().assertIsEnabled()
    }

    @Test
    fun `MyComposable - when button clicked - performs action`() {
        var buttonClicked = false
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            MyComposable(onClick = { buttonClicked = true })
        }
        composeTestRule.mainClock.advanceTimeByFrame()

        buttonNode.performClick()

        assertTrue(buttonClicked)
    }

}
```